# Haiku Extractor

Tags: text, string-manipulation

Inspired by the cool Tumblr [Haiku Times](http://haiku.nytimes.com/) that searches for accidental haiku in New York Times articles, I tried my hand at implementing such a search in Mathematica for my own text samples.

I'm still not a one-liner writer, so I'd welcome any input on more efficient approaches than mine below (especially the Table in Step 4!), but to follow the rules my question is how to implement my Step 6 automatically as I'm doing it manually now:

Step 1. Read in text

```
sampleText =  "Haikus are easy but sometimes they don't make sense refrigerator. Make a man a king today and tomorrow he will be a brigand. Dragonflies, by contrast, look dainty, glittery and fun, like a bubble bath or costume jewelry, and they're often grouped with butterflies and ladybugs on the very short list of Insects People Like.";
```

Step 2. Break up paragraphs into sentences at periods

```
sampleSentences = StringSplit[sampleText,"."]
```

Step 3. Break up sentences into words

```
sampleWords = StringSplit[sampleSentences]
```

Step 4. Count each sentence's syllables

```
syllableCount[x_] := Length[WordData[x, "Hyphenation"]]
sampleSyllables = 
 Table[Apply[Plus, 
   Map[syllableCount, ToLowerCase[sampleWords[[i]]]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[sampleWords]}]

{16, 17, 41}
```

Step 5. Select the sentences with 17 syllables

```
sampleHaiku = 
 sampleSentences[[Flatten[Position[sampleSyllables, 17]]]]

{" Make a man a king today and tomorrow he will be a brigand"}
```

Ironically:

```
syllableCount["haikus"]

1
```

Step 6. Break the 17-syllabic ones up at 5, 7, 5 and display the result
(I ran out of ideas here...)

Thanks in advance and apologies for protocol/formatting gaffes on my first post!

Comment: It's a fine question and well posted in my opinion.

Comment: WordData words listing isn't very comprehensive. Try  `WordData["haikus", "Hyphenation"]`. But `haiku` works, though

Comment: *English "written" syllables therefore do not correspond to the actually spoken syllables of the living language* (Wikipedia). Might that imply that hyphenation data is not the correct method to count syllables in a haiku ( which is intended to be read aloud)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As belisarius noted in a comment above, `WordData` can sometimes be inadequate. It might be more robust (but slower) if we use Wolfram | Alpha from inside *Mathematica* to retrive the syllable count with the following function:

```
ClearAll@syllables
SetAttributes[syllables, Listable]
syllables[word_String] := Length@WolframAlpha[
   "syllables " <> word, {{"Hyphenation:WordData", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

Here's a haiku splitter based on the above function. If a haiku is not possible, it returns `$Failed`:

```
haikuSplit[str_String] := 
    With[{s = Accumulate@syllables@#},
        With[{l = s /. {a___, 5, b___, 12, c___, 17} :> Length /@ {{a}, {b}, {c}} + 1},
            If[l === s,
                Print["No haiku possible!"]; $Failed,
                Composition[StringJoin, Riffle[#, " "] &] /@ 
                    Internal`PartitionRagged[#, l] // TableForm
            ]
        ]
    ] &@StringSplit[str, Whitespace]
```

Now let's test this:

```
haikuSplit["Make a man a king today and tomorrow he will be a brigand"]
(*  Make a man a king
    today and tomorrow he
    will be a brigand *)

haikuSplit["Make a man a king today and tomorrow he will be a haiku expert"]
(*  No haiku possible!
    $Failed *)
```

Comment: `WolframAlpha["syllables dragonflies",{{"Hyphenation:WordData", 1}, "ComputableData"}]` misses data, yet W|A does recompute with "dragonfly" and returns its hyphenation. `WolframAlpha["hyphenate " <> "dragonflies", "PodCells"]`. It's the same number of syllables.

Comment: Hmm... it's probably because W|A interprets the plural form of the animal/plant name as referring to the class of animals instead of just the word. It also fails with `lions`, `tigers`, `cats`, `dogs`, `elephants`,... I don't use W|A all that much, so I am not sure if it is possible to force it to interpret it as a word instead.

Comment: It fails here and there, yes. How complex would you say the engine behind the mentioned [Times Haiku](http://haiku.nytimes.com/) is? Such a tiny, yet fascinating blog.

Comment: I'm sure the NYT engine is written in something like perl. There are several advanced packages available for NLP in perl (e.g. see [this](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-Syllable/Syllable.pm)) and it probably is no more than half a page or 2 at most of code. Even those might not be 100% accurate (although the situations in which they fail are different). Syllable counting is not easy and English, being a mongrel language, makes things much harder than say, for German. Of course, the problem with German is that you hit 17 syllables before  the second word, thus making haikus impossible ;)

Comment: Could one utilize LaTeX hyphenating in Mathematica instead of WordData or W|A (which share database I guess), would that be very hard to achieve? Since it seems very powerful to me. (And a package for my mother tongue, Slovene exists for bonus.)

Comment: @BoLe Is it possible? Most likely yes. Is it easy? Most likely no :) That said, I don't know how to do it, but automatic Haiku detection is just a passing fad. There aren't good NLP packages for mma probably because it just isn't used as much in the field, which in turn is because perl is much more powerful and faster. If I were to do NLP for a living, I'd probably learn perl too.

Answer (score 2):

Step 2. Append an empty space to dot.

```
sampleSentences = StringSplit[sampleText, ". "]
```

Step 4. Function `syllableCount` defined by you.

```
Total /@ Map[syllableCount, StringSplit[sampleSentences], {2}]
```

> {16, 17, 40}

Step 5. The 17-syllable sentences.

```
h = Select[sampleSentences,
 Total[syllableCount /@ StringSplit[#]] == 17 &]
```

> {"Make a man a king today and tomorrow he will be a brigand"}

Step 6. Breaking of a string in three 5-, 7- and 5-syllable strings.

```
cut[haiku_] :=
 Module[{words = StringSplit[haiku, " "], h2},
  h2 = Accumulate[syllableCount /@ words];
  Apply[StringJoin, Riffle[Take[words, #], " "]] & /@
   (Position[h2, 5 | 12] /. {{i_}, {j_}} :>
      {{1, i}, {i + 1, j}, {j + 1, -1}})]
```

Breaking selected sentences.

```
cut /@ h
```

> {{"Make a man a king", "today and tomorrow he", "will be a brigand"}}

```
StringJoin[Riffle[cut@#, "\n"] & /@ h]
```

> Make a man a king
>   today and tomorrow he
>   will be a brigand

Comment: Please try `WordData[#, "Hyphenation"] & /@ ToLowerCase[sampleWords[[2]]]` . Your result is right, but only by chance

Comment: This still returns some `Missing["NotAvailable"]` elements albeit fewer. I saw that but I figured only one syllable words are missing hyphenation data (??), and `syllableCount` measures them correctly as an element list.

Comment: Not the case. Try `WordData["Haikus","Hyphenation"]`

Comment: Oops, I noticed a mistake with arguments for `Take` in `cut`. I fixed it with an explicit rule.

Comment: @belisarius I see, `WordData` doesn't have anything on it. Let's hope there won't be any "haikus" in haiku sentences of text. :)

Comment: `"Haikus"` is the first word in the first sentence in the question. Sorry. :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thoughtful comments and answer, @BoLe, +1 for the answer because I can't choose both! Your suggestions condensed my initial code nicely.

Comment: @sftmtrhkr I'm glad. There are more things to implement though. Did you take care of commas? You could `StringTrim` a word moment before hyphenating it via `WordData` or other service. What about abbreviations like don't, aren't, you're? Do they perchance all have two syllables by default? Stay in touch about this "passing fad", why don't you.

Comment: @BoLe I appreciate the feedback. Delighted to follow up. What's the best approach/etiquette for staying in touch?  Adding comments for small updates and posting a new question for a more significant point?

Comment: @sftmtrhkr I'm new here too. I guess you can pose a new question about it have you made significant progress and stumbled upon a new problem. On the other hand you can always update the question here, or eventually answer you own question. With the grand solution. Both times it will reappear top under *Top Questions*. Regarding the solution, I think the first thing is to find a reliable hyphenation service other than `WordData`, *rm -rf* mentions packages ... Parsing text should be fun afterwards. (Me you can also mail personally at "bole79 at gmail".)